# Count books of user with Linq-To-Sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm new in linq and i have a simple problem.
i must count how many books have user.
i know its easy but i cant do this.

//database

[image]

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetAllUsers()
{
    var result = from u in databaseContext.User
                    select new UserViewModel
                    {
                        UserId = u.UserId,
                        LastName = u.LastName,
                        FirstName = u.FirstName,
                        BirthDate = u.BirthDate,
                        Email = u.Email,
                        Phone = u.Phone,
                        AddDate = u.AddDate,
                        ModifiedDate = u.ModifiedDate,
                        IsActive = u.IsActive,  

                    };
    return result.ToList();
}
```

how to do this?

Comment: Do you want unreturned books (`IsReturned=false`) or, all books a user has ever borrowed? or the number of books borrowed in a date range?

Comment: "How many books have user" ==> where is your book context and how does it look like? (I'm unable to see anything following your link)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! What have you tried yourself? You've obviously had issue with some code, otherwise you wouldn't ask this question, right? =)

Comment: @Jamiec i  must count only books user have at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

In your model it seems that every Borrow has exactly one Book associated with it. If that is the case and the books cannot be taken more than once (which should be also correct) then all you need to do is:

```
int count = context.Users.First(x=>x.UserId = 1).Borrow.Count();
```

This way you can count all the Borrows of a given user supposing that they are all associated with a book.

If two borrows can have the same book than you should slightly rewrite this query to this:

```
int count = db.Borrow.Where(x => x.UserID== 1).Select(x => x.BookId).Distinct().Count();
```

This way you will get only the unique books borrowed from the user with id of 1.

To count only the unique books that are not returned use this:

```
int count = db.Borrow.Where(x => x.UserID== 1 && x.IsReturned == false).Select(x => x.BookId).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: thank you so much! another question. if i want to find number of books for every user in list? not for one number UserId